# AS3/Flash, How to make a button to browse and load dynamic text files within this code?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

This is a script that loads the specified .log (text) file and shows its content dynamically in the movie (artist and song from the current track played).

Because the player makes new .log files after a certain time, I need to select the latest .log file manually when starting the .swf or when it changes during the session. What I am doing, is opening the **trackLogNum.txt** file and writing there the 5 NUMBER section (logNum variable) of the .log filename structure, which is, i.e. *127.0.0.1,12345.log*

Is there any way to implement a button in this code to browse the .log files in the directory and then select and load the latest one, instead of writing each time the filename in the external **trackLogNum.txt**?

*I think it would be perfect a function that loads automatically the newest .log file (as I see in dynamically loading of pictures within slideshows, which frequently have breadcrumb buttons to go to the first and also the last item), but they said it is not possible without using PHP or Flex. As you notice in the code, it is a local application, no server is running.*

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
var reload:Timer = new Timer(5000, 1); 
reload.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer); 

//--------------------

var logNumLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
logNumLoader.dataFormat=URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
logNumLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadedLogNum);
logNumLoader.load(new URLRequest("trackLogNum.txt"));
var _logNum:String;

function loadedLogNum(e:Event):void {

     trace(e.target.data.logNum);
        _logNum = e.target.data.logNum;
        loadTracks();
    }

//--------------------

var tracksLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
tracksLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onTracksLoaded);
tracksLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,onTracksError);
tracksLoader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR,onTracksError);

loadTracks();

function onTracksLoaded(e:Event):void {
    trace("onTracksLoaded");
    parseTracks(tracksLoader.data); 
    reload.start(); 
 }

function onTimer(event:TimerEvent):void{ 
    loadTracks();
}

function onTracksError(e:Event):void {
    trace("onTracksError", e);
    reload.start();
}

function loadTracks():void {
    tracksLoader.load(new URLRequest("127.0.0.1,"+_logNum+".log")); 
}

function parseTracks(data:String):void {
    try {
        var lines:Array = data.split("\n"); 
        var lastLine:String = lines[lines.length - 2]; 
        var artistAndSong:String = lastLine.substr(24).split(" - ").join("\n\n->");
        trace(artistAndSong);
        track_info.text = artistAndSong; 
        addChild(track_info);
    } catch(e:Error) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There exists a [flash.filesystem](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/package-detail.html) available for Actionscript 3.0 that offers some interesting classes to browser a directory. Sadly and for security reasons mainly, it is only available when compiling your project against AIR. Have you considered creating an AIR application instead of a normal swf?

In order to use the filesystem package (and be able to browser your log files) you will need to convert your application to an AIR application. You can do this by changing the publication settings:

[image]

I found [a good example](http://snipplr.com/view/25109/get-all-files-from-a-folder/) on how to browser all files on the desktop.

Comment: It is Flash CS4, and I don´t care about using Air, if I can use this script in a second monitor in full screen (It is what I´m doing now, embedding the .swf within a browser). The question is that I have no idea on how to change this code exactly for what I want, because I haven´t found any references regarding this issue. Could you be more specific if you guess how to make it work? Thank you very much.

Comment: I have published my Air app and installed it, but sorry, I don´t understand the example to make it work implemented in my code. And another question is that I need to run it in full screen. I have founded it http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Using_the_FullScreen_functionality_in_AIR-8004.html also but I am not sure what I need to do with it. I am not used to work with Air apps.

Comment: I have found that it is possible to browse files from .swf in local, look this tutorial http://www.emanuelz.com.mx/blog/browsing-and-loading-local-files-using-filereference-class-54

Comment: Yes, but it only allows you to load a specific file from the file system. I though that you wanted to browse all files from a specific folder in order to find the newest log.

Comment: @jdecuyper, as I don´t know how to make this, I have asked here: http://www.rent-acoder.com/cgi-bin/rent-acoder/project.cgi?id=1290077664 If you would like to apply there to make this working in Flash or Air (I need the full screen option active in Air), perfect.

Comment: Thanks Pablo. Could you please send me an email at: jerome.decuyper[at]gmail.com